# How to handle browser history using History class

Tags: dart, html5-history

So I'm learning dart and web development in general. Right now I'm experimenting with the history API. I have:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  ParagraphElement paragraph = querySelector('.parag');

  ButtonElement buttonOne = querySelector('.testaja');

  buttonOne.onClick.listen((_) {
    window.history.pushState(null, 'test title', '/testdata/');
    window.history.forward();
  });

  ButtonElement buttonTwo = querySelector('.testlagi');

  buttonTwo.onClick.listen((_) {
    window.history.back();
  });

  window.onPopState.listen((_) {
    window.alert(window.location.pathname);
  });
}
```

My conclusion is that `onPopState` only triggers when we click on browser's back or forward button, or using `window.history.forward()` or `window.history.back()`. So this is like, we render a template, then change its url using `pushState`, not update template based on url changes. Is this true or not?

Edit:

So maybe I'm not clear enough. Let's say I have something like this:

```dart
void main() {
  InputElement input = querySelector('.input')
  ButtonElement changeUrl = querySelector('.change-url');

  changeUrl.onClick.listen((event) {
    window.history.pushState(null, 'test tile', input.value);
  });

  Map urls = {
    '/' : showRoot,
    '/user/:id' : showUserProfile
  };

  window.onPopState.listen((_) {
    var location = window.location.pathname;

    urls[location]();
  });
}
```

I can get `input`'s value by clicking on `changeUrl`, and then by adding a listener to `changeUrl`, I can use `pushState` to update url on browser. What I'm expecting is, when I do `pushState`, the `window.onPopState` will triggered and invoke the callback when in reality it doesn't.

tldr, what I'm trying to achieve is:

listen on url changes -> get current url -> use current url to invoke a handler stored in a map. Using `onHashChange` also doesn't work when updating url using `pushState` prefixed by `#`.

Comment: I read you question several times but I am still not sure what you are asking. Does something not work as expected?

Comment: Edited my answer. I think I now understood you question. If you don't think so, write a comment and I take another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**

set the hash using

```dart
window.location.hash = input.value;
```

this triggers the `PopState` and `HashChange` event

as does a click on such a link

```html
<a href="#abc">abc</a>
```

**original**

I don't have time to take a close look what you'r trying to achive..
But I think you should add an event handler for 'window.onHashChange' this way ordinary links work too for navigation, not only buttons with onclick-handlers modifying browser history.