# How can detect Url anchor change with Dart?

Tags: dart

How to detect change in urls anchor and handle it. 
For example:

```
when url is abc:8080/#toys do actionToys()
when url is abc:8080/#books do actionBooks()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle browser history using History class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206450/how-to-handle-browser-history-using-history-class)

Comment: If the references question/answer doesn't help leave a comment here. You may also take a look at router packages like http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/route, http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/route_hierarchical which help you manage uls and history (keep back button working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example of what i think you need

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  //Register listener for Hash Change event
  window.onHashChange.listen((HashChangeEvent e) {
    //Capture Hash
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    //Check hash
    if(hash == "#toys"){
      actionToys();
    } else if(hash == "#books"){
      actionBooks();
    }
  });
}

void actionToys (){
  window.alert("TOYS");
}

void actionBooks (){
  window.alert("BOOKS");
}
```